# jQuery slider value above slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider that I need help changing, when I slide the slider the value should appear above the slider.

This is my slider / values:
http://gyazo.com/342b1592d5d175b7321efb36cbc2424c

Also my slider value should be whatever the first value of the slider is and NOT 0.

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var valMap = [0, 6500, 14000, 28000, 50000];
    $( ".slider.gems" ).slider({
        max: valMap.length - 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $(".number.gems").text(ui.value);
            $(".number.gems" ).text(valMap[ui.value]);
        }
    });
    $( ".number.gems" ).text( $( ".slider.gems" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

Comment: You should mention which slider plugin you are using.

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/xwqprc6a/?

Comment: @Sushil that works, thank you but how do i get the start value to 6500 instead of 0, if i remove 0 from the var it still only starts from 0.

Comment: @chrismasefield I've posted my solution as an answer. please upvote it and mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this.
set the `min` value of the slider to 1 and create an event handler for `slide` and `create` events which will update the slider value

this is the html

```
<div style='padding: 5px;'>
    <div id="gems"></div>
</div>
```

here's what your js should look like

```
var gems = $("#gems"),
    initialValue = 0;

var valMap = [0, 6500, 14000, 28000, 50000];

var updateSliderValue = function(e, ui) {
    var slider = $(this).data().slider;

    slider.element.find(".ui-slider-handle").text(valMap[ui.value]);
};
console.log(valMap.length);

gems.slider({
    min: 1,
    max: (valMap.length - 1),
    slide: updateSliderValue,
    create: updateSliderValue,
    value: 6500
});
```

and here's how your css should be

```
#gems {
    margin: 60px 30px 0 30px     
}

#gems > .ui-slider-handle {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xwqprc6a/2/)** for the same.

Comment: that's perfect other than the fact that the numbers on the slider should be above the slider, if thats possible. Sorry to be a pain but I have no knowledge at all with this.

Comment: let me try that tomorrow if thats not too late for u.

Comment: That's perfect, please do.

Comment: great then. i'll try to change it first thing in the morning tomorrow

Comment: any luck with making those changes?

Comment: just got into office. give me a couple of hours

Comment: is there any way to contact you outside of here? Im having major difficulty incorporating it into my site and can't upload files or anything here.

Comment: instead of 1 it should be the slider value e.g. 6500 or 50000 
http://gyazo.com/d130f660c68f885bad7c4343203eef13

Comment: hey hi. sorry i wont be available on office hours outside of stackoverflow.

Comment: as for your value, how are you displaying the value? how are you getting it?

Comment: u cannot use the same id for 2 different elements. id's must be unique

Comment: so how do I make the value of the slider match the one thats displayed on the right hand side?

Comment: do this $( ".number" ).text( curValue ); instead of taking the slider value, display the curvalue. it will work. replace this $( ".number#gems" ).text( $( ".slider#gems" ).slider( "value" ) ); with $( ".number" ).text( curValue );

Comment: Thank you so much!! it worked..

When I duplicate it like this: http://pastebin.com/8PNYayyq both sliders move together.

Comment: you need to create a separate function for the other slider. create a new function updateGoldSliderValue

Comment: I did that but the tooltip values on all sliders change too.

Comment: m glad I was able to help you. are you on linkedin?

Comment: you can repay me by helping someone else when you get a chance :)